# Move thumbnail next and prev jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Friends i want to move my thumbnails next and prev with using jquery i found many jquery with same effects but problem is when i implement those code in my code then my existing code conflicting with this code .I want this kind of effect http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html. I am new in jquery i dont know how to start. My html code is following

**HTML**

```
   <div id="img">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="foundation.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
        <li><img src="mobile3.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
        <li><img src="template.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
     </ul>   
   </div>     
     <div id="next">next</div>
     <div id="prev">prev</div>
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you try looking at the page source - http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html also look at the JS and css includes

Comment: yes i tried its conflicting with code..

Answer (score 0):

Simply you should download the jCoursel plugin and use it. [Here is the link to download it.](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/)